# The texture of the player does not changing

Tags: c++, sfml

In the code I wrote, the collision is detected correctly, but only 1 enemy changes players texture. **What is the reason and how can I change players texture for every enemy?** The problem is between lines ***56 and 64*** of the code.

Screenshots :

[No collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LpW1.png)

[Collision but texture isn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw1Ho.png)

[Collision and players texture is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goxx6.png)

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main(){

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500,500), "Game");
    window.setFramerateLimit(100);

    Texture playerTexture;
    playerTexture.loadFromFile("./images/player.png");
    Texture collisionPlayerTexture;
    collisionPlayerTexture.loadFromFile("./images/collision_player.png");
    Texture enemyTexture;
    enemyTexture.loadFromFile("./images/enemy.png");

    Sprite player;
    player.setTexture(playerTexture);
    player.setTextureRect(IntRect(50,50,50,50));
    player.setPosition(225,225);

    Sprite enemies[5] = {Sprite(),Sprite(),Sprite(),Sprite(),Sprite()};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        enemies[i].setTexture(enemyTexture);
        enemies[i].setTextureRect(IntRect(25,25,25,25));
        enemies[i].setPosition(rand() % 475,rand() % 475);
    }

    while(window.isOpen()){

        Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
            }
        }

        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W) || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)){
            player.move(0.0f,-1.5f);
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::S) || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)){
            player.move(0.0f,1.5f);
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A) || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)){
            player.move(-1.5f,0.0f);
        }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D) || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)){
            player.move(1.5f,0.0f);
        }

        window.clear(Color(255,255,255));

        //////////////////////////////////////////////This is where I'm talking about//////////////////////////////////////////////

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            if(player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(enemies[i].getGlobalBounds())){
                std::cout << "Collision"; // This is working
                player.setTexture(collisionPlayerTexture); // But this line only works for an enemy
            } else {
                player.setTexture(playerTexture);
            }
            window.draw(enemies[i]);
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////This is where I'm talking about//////////////////////////////////////////////

        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
```

you are iterating through all 5 enemies.

If you detect collision with the LAST one, you change the texture and get out of the loop. But if the collision was with any other enemy, the next loop iteration will revert the texture back.

Solution: you might want to `break;` out of the loop if a collision was detected.